# What am I doing wrong? (Simple Assembly Loop)

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPViS.jpg]

It won't let me post the picture. Btw, Someone from Reddit.programming sent me over here. So thanks!

```
TITLE MASM Template

; Description
;
; Revision date:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myArray BYTE 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF myArray
    mov eax, 0
L1:
    add eax, [esi]
    inc esi
    loop L1
    call WriteInt
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Results in:

```
-334881242
```

Comment: Can you post the code? I can barely make it out.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Maybe your `WriteInt` function should be inside the loop? And make sure it only prints the value of one byte because it seems that it prints a 32-bit value.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gjUbV.jpg

That's the full image. I blows up significantly

Comment: What is it doing now and what are you expecting it to do? Please post a decent question so we can actually help you.

Comment: It's supposed to add the values in the array together, resulting in an output of 550

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. So `WriteInt` prints the content of `eax`. You correctly set `eax` to zero. Could you please try `add eax, byte [esi]` instead of `add eax, [esi]`?!

Answer (score 4):

You have to cast the value to a byte pointer instead of 32 bit pointer.

Change

```
add eax, [esi]
```

to

```
add eax, byte ptr [esi]
```

Comment: That will not work: **error A2022:instruction operands must be the same size**

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a DWORD from a byte table, so masm gives you an error.Forcing byte size here using BYTE PTR is gonna get you a masm error (invalid operand or something alike), because you can't directly add a byte to a DWORD.

But there are still several ways to do what you want. 
Here is one that costs an extra register (EDX):

```
(...)
    mov edx, 0         ; We want the upper 3 bytes to zero.
    mov eax, 0

L1:
    mov dl, [esi]      ; Inject one byte from the table,
    add eax, edx       ;  upper bytes still zero, so EDX has your byte value.
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's the thing:

My guess is that WriteInt expects a 32-bit signed value in EAX. Therefore you could do:

```
movzx eax, BYTE PTR [esi]
inc esi 
call WriteInt 

loop L1 
-- or --
dec ecx
jnz L1
```

Or if you are sure that WriteInt do not touch EAX you can do:

```
xor eax,eax ; clear EAX
L1:
lodsb ; loads a byte into AL and increments ESI for you
call WriteInt
loop L1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myArray BYTE 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100

.code
main PROC
    call Clrscr
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF myArray
    xor eax, eax
L1:
    add eax, byte ptr [esi]
    inc esi
    loop L1
    call WriteInt
    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I'm assuming, `WriteInt` is taking a parameter in EAX to print out the results, since the code failed because you were using a 32bit pointer to the offset into the data within the `ESI` register, change that to a `byte ptr` in order to get the proper 8 bits (a byte). Also, use of `XOR` would be faster than a `MOV` instruction for the `EAX` register, then the code should work...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: `add eax, byte ptr [esi]` will throw an error: error A2022:instruction operands must be the same size